# Making sense of injected components wrapped in an if statement

Tags: javascript, reactjs

I have the following return statement in an App.jsx

```
  return (
    <div className="App">
      <Header />
      <ThemeSwitch />
      <div style={{ textAlign: "center", padding: 10 }}>
        <Account 
           connectText={"Connect Ethereum Wallet"}
        />
      </div>

      {display}

    </div>
  );
```

The `{display}` code is as follows:

```
const [result, setResult] = useState();

let display = "";
  if (result) {
    ...
    display = (
      <div style={{ marginTop: 32 }}>
        {result.replace(possibleTxId, "")} {extraLink}
      </div>
    );
  } else if (isSigner) {
    display = (
      <Button
        onClick={async () => {
          setLoading(true);
          try {
              ...
              const res = await axios.post(serverUrl, {
                address: address,
                message: message,
                signature: sig,
              });
              if (res.data) {
                setResult(res.data);
              }
            } else {
              setLoading(false);
              setResult(" Sorry, the server is overloaded. Please try again later. ⏳");
            }
          } catch (e) {
            message.error(" Sorry, the server is overloaded. ");
            console.log("FAILED TO GET...");
          }
        }}
      >
        <span style={{ marginRight: 8 }}></span> sign a message with your ethereum wallet
      </Button>
    );
```

The app consists of a single button that when clicks signs in, it then `{displays}`s based on the `if(result)` statement

I don't quite understand how `{display}` is displaying anything at all because I cannot see how the `if(result)` statement is fired?

Comment: The `setResult` function is a React state hook. When called it changes the `result` value and it also triggers a new render of the component which displays the other JSX as the `result` value has changed

Answer (score 1, accepted):

`result` is by default `undefined` since no initial state is provided:

```
const [result, setResult] = useState();
```

Which makes this condition `false`:

```
if (result) {
```

So as long as `result` is `undefined`, `display` will render whatever is set to it in the `else` block, which is a `<Button/>`.  But that `<Button/>` is used to *update* `result`:

```
setResult(res.data);
```

or:

```
setResult(" Sorry, the server is overloaded. Please try again later. ⏳");
```

In either case, `result` gets updated to some defined value.  An object, a string, something.  So when the component re-renders, `result` will have a value and this will evaluate to `true`:

```
if (result) {
```

Which will then set `display` to the `<div>` in the `if` block.

Basically it's all driven by whatever the current state is of the React component.  When the state is updated, the component re-renders with the new state.

Comment: Hi David, I am comfortable with what the if statement is doing, but not how it is doing it.  Does that if statement run each time state changes? So does ALL code run when the state changes?

Comment: @mickeysox: This is core to how React itself works.  The framework will automatically re-render components when the state driving those components is updated.  In this case there's one element of state: `result`.  So any time something calls `setResult` to update that state, it will trigger this component (`<App/>`?) to render again.  For older class components this will at least re-invoke the `render` method.  For modern function components this will re-execute the component function.  (During which time `useState` will also be called, but internally knows not to re-set the state.)

Comment: Understood, however the only place setResult is called is inside the else if block.  When I sign into my app, 2 things happen, setResult is called, and the message "sign a message with your ethereum wallet" but my confusion still remains, how is the if / else if statement called, if the only time setResult is called is inside the else if block?

Comment: @mickeysox: Because calling `setResult` triggers the component to re-render, which re-invokes the component function itself.  That function contains the `if (result) {` code, so that code is executed when that function is invoked.

Comment: I get that calling setResult will re-render the component, but in order for the else if to run, and therefore setResult, the if (result) statement first needs to run, by the nature that we are in else if, means if must have run correct?  So what calls the if first time round to enable setResult to run?

Comment: @mickeysox: You're over-complicating this.  Every time a function is called, the code within that function is executed, right?  The component is a function.  When it gets rendered, that function is called.  That function includes the if statement in question.  *Every time* the component renders, the `if` statement is invoked.  The value of `result` may be different from one render to the next, resulting in different behavior.  But overall what you're seeing here is that when a function is called its code is executed, no different from any function anywhere.

Comment: Thanks David, appreciate you taking the time.